# jQuery-ui autocomplete element click works only first time in IE

Tags: jquery-ui

```
$('#ac').autocomplete({
        source: '/url',
        appendTo: $('#ac').closest('.popupWindow'),
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
```

in IE9 first time everything works fine, but when i type text is second time, elements don`t reacts on clicks

error appears only when using `appendTo` option

Comment: which error? jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: theres no error throws, theres no any reaction on my click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it: on one of parent elements was click event handler with `e.stopPropagation()`